# Time limit before edits commit to revision history

Tags: support

In reviewing a suggested edit I made some further improvements and then realised moments later I'd made an incorrect assumption that the OP was using a pair of microcontrollers, considering it was a CAN bus it could have involved more than two devices so I removed my reference to a pair. It is edit three on the following revision list:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/64220/revisions

Apart from my misspelling of 'possiblly' in the edit summary it looks a bit odd now because my first edit has been rolled into the second but using the second edit summary where I'd just removed a "pair of" microcontrollers. No big deal but I wondered for future reference how long you get to re-edit a post without it appearing as a distinct edit?

Comment: I don't think you get any time to edit your edit. Just edit it again.

Comment: @CamilStaps, that's what I did but the two edits were combined on the history, so it had the right end result but left the edit summary looking odd because the first edit  doesn't show where I'd mentioned a pair of micros.

Comment: Ahh, now I understand!

Comment: I think the limit is 5 minutes.

Comment: Twice today I made a comment and trying to put in a line feed with Shift-Enter it goes to the next line and then accepts the comment right after.  I have not finished or checked the first part so obviously I say edit to complete my comment, however I now have an 5 min deadline to complete something that I did expect to hit.  more to follow

Comment: (continuation) 
The second time I am trapped again selected and copied the data, cancelled, deleted the comment and made another and when I was about to paste my comment in again it was not in my clipboard.  As a result I put in only part of what I planned to say because repetition to cover for user interface limitations gets old fast.  Having the 5 (preferably 10) min restart every time you save the comment would be nice if you save it by accident the first time and need more time to complete it rather than just a quick typo fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a 5 minute limit. This has been discussed many times on Meta.StackOverflow if you want to know more about it.

I believe one of the staff said that if they logged every single edit as a separate revision it would add a huge load on their database, as most people reread their posts and edit typos immediately after posting.